# Easily create (copy) methods in Javapoet using methods from annotated code

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing, javapoet

I wrote an annotation processor that creates a subclass. For example, if you have the following code:

```
@MyAnnotation(Bar.class)
class Foo : MyGenerated_Foo {
}
```

Then the annotation processor generates:

```
class MyGenerated_Foo extends Bar {
  ... generate some helpful methods and fields here ...
}
```

After using this for a while I realized this doesn't work if Bar has a custom constructor. I'd like to create a pass through constructor but I wasn't sure what the best way to do that is.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
class Bar {
  Bar(String arg) {}
}

@MyAnnotation(Bar.class)
class Foo : MyGenerated_Foo {
  Foo(String arg) {
    MyGenerated_Foo(arg);
  }
}
```

the above could should generate the following:

```
class MyGenerated_Foo extends Bar {
  MyGenerated_Bar(String arg) {
    Bar(arg);
  }

  ... generate some helpful methods and fields here ...
}
```